How to solve this difficult differential equation with Runge-Kutta methods?
Given the following differential equation (it can be seen as a matrix differential equation):
$$\begin{cases}
x'=\dfrac{dx}{d\phi}=\dfrac{ \cos(\phi) }{ 2+\beta z-(1/x) \sin(\phi) } \\
z'=\dfrac{dz}{d\phi}=\dfrac{ \sin(\phi) }{ 2+\beta z-(1/x) \sin(\phi) } \\
x(\phi=0)=0; \\ z(\phi=0)=0 
\end{cases} $$
How can I solve this using a Runge-Kutta method? $\phi$ exists in $[0,\pi/2]$. Thank you for the attention!
I've tried the following code:
function [T,V]=capillaryrisesol(N)

beta=80;

f=@(phi,x,z) [ (cos(phi))/(2+beta*z-(sin(phi)/x) ) ; (sin(phi))/(2+beta*z-(sin(phi)/x ))];

a=0.0000000001; b=pi/2;

v0=[a ;a];

m=length(v0);

h=( b-0 )/N;

T=zeros(1,N+1); V=zeros(m,N+1);

V(:,1)=v0; T(1)=0;

k1=f(T(1),a,a);

k2=f( T(1)+h/2, a + (h/2)*k1(1), a + (h/2)*k1(2)  );

k3=f( T(1)+h/2, a + (h/2)*k2(1), a + (h/2)*k2(2) );

k4=f( T(1)+h, a+h*k3(1),  a+h*k3(2) );

for n=1:N

    T(n+1)=0+n*h;

    V(:,n+1)=V(:,n) + (h/6)*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4);

end

But it results in an straight line. In fact, in order to plot all the pairs values given by V columns, I used: plot( V(1,:), V(2, :) ).

Maybe the code plot( V(1,:), V(2, :) ) is not optimal? Or that's something wrong in the code. Thanks for reading!
UPGRADES: I've tried to use the following code for plotting:
[T,V]=capillaryrisesol(50);
V1=V(1,:); V2=V(2,:);
semilogx(V1,V2)

Resulting in:

The fact is that the function should increase at lower x. Here it starts to increase after 100, that's too much I think.
Thanks to Lutz Lehmann I've improved the code as follow:

beta=80;

f=@(phi,x,z) [ (cos(phi))/(2+beta*z-(sin(phi)/x) ) ; (sin(phi))/(2+beta*z-(sin(phi)/x ))];

a=0.0000000001;
b=pi/2;

v0=[a ;0];

m=length(v0);

h=( b-0 )/N;
h=h;

T=zeros(1,N+1);
V=zeros(m,N+1);

V(:,1)=v0;
T(1)=a;

for n=1:N

    T(n+1)=0+n*h;

    k1=f(T(n+1),a,a);

    k2=f( T(n+1)+h/2, V(1,n) + (h/2)*k1(1), V(2,n) + (h/2)*k1(2)  );

    k3=f( T(n+1)+h/2, V(1,n) + (h/2)*k2(1), V(2,n) + (h/2)*k2(2) );

    k4=f( T(n+1)+h, V(1,n)+h*k3(1),  V(2,n)+h*k3(2) );

    V(:,n+1)=V(:,n) + (h/6)*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4);

end

I've tried to fix the loop, using the previous values found for the new iteration. Using semilogx, it results in:

Is it possible to get better result?
4TH TRY:

beta=80;

f=@(phi,x,z) [ (cos(phi))/(2+beta*z-(sin(phi)/x) ) ; (sin(phi))/(2+beta*z-(sin(phi)/x ))];

a=0.000001;
b=pi/2;

v0=[a ;0];

m=length(v0);

T=linspace(0,b,N+1);
T(1)=a;
V=zeros(m,N+1);

V(:,1)=v0;

for n=1:N

    h=T(n+1)-T(n);

    k1=f(T(n),V(1,n),V(2,n));

    k2=f( T(n)+h/2, V(1,n) + (h/2)*k1(1), V(2,n) + (h/2)*k1(2)  );

    k3=f( T(n)+h/2, V(1,n) + (h/2)*k2(1), V(2,n) + (h/2)*k2(2) );

    k4=f( T(n)+h, V(1,n)+h*k3(1),  V(2,n)+h*k3(2) );

    V(:,n+1)=V(:,n) + (h/6)*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4);

end

Resulting in:

What do you think? Thanks for the attention!

Hi @fede1602, and welcome to MSE! It looks to me like the standard RK4 algorithm will work just fine on your system, so you will probably have more luck getting good answers if you can be more specific about what your difficulty is.

The initial point is not in the domain of the ODE system. One would need to perform an asymptotic analysis to determine if the initial point can occur as limit of any solution.

@LutzLehmann that's a good point. Is it possible to solve this issue by assuming x(phi=0)=0.001, a sort of "engineer-like zero"?

You can do that, but following that solution backwards may be unstable, in that the solution itself diverges for $x\to0$ or that variations like $x(0)=0.002$ may give a large difference to the first solution.

@SortofDamocles I've tried to code a RK4 algorithm, but the graph (X-Z) results in a straight line. In reality it should be an increasing curve. How can I share my code? The comment section have a chars limit. I'm sorry, I'm a newby

The comment section is intended to be only for comments. Substantial insights are to be added to the question by OP or as answers by others. So use the "Edit" link below the question and add a section with code. You can also add a plot, as essential part of the question it will likely be activated.

@LutzLehmann Thank you very much!

Assuming that the solution is not only finite at $\phi\to0$, but also differentiable, one can replace the critical term as difference quotient in the limit differential quotient
$$
\frac{\sin\phi}{x(\phi)}\to\frac1{x'(0)}
$$
Then, for this point only
$$
\frac1{x'(0)}=2-\frac1{x'(0)}\implies x'(0)=1
$$
and $z'(0)=0$. One way forward is to use this in a small extra Euler step, with a step size $\delta$ that gives a unit step error that is comparable to the rest of the integration with a higher order method and larger step size. For RK4 for example $\delta = h^4$. Or use a higher order method for the initial step, like explicit or implicit midpoint method with $\delta = h^2$. Or do a separate RK4 step with the same step size.
Solutions with $x(0)\ne 0$ will have $x'(0)=\frac12$, but should curve upwards very quickly to avoid intersecting the above solution. Such a quick turn might be missed if the step size is too large, so numerical solutions may cross, contrary to the behavior of the exact solutions.

To the code: As $\phi$ is an active variable, you should not change it around. Thus the $T$ array should start with $T(1)=a$ and $V(:,1)=[a,0]$ as result of the above mentioned small Euler step.
The stages $k_1,..,k_4$ need to be computed in every time step, otherwise the solution is for a different ODE with constant right side which indeed has linear solutions.
Remember that semilogx only has a logarithmic scale on the x-axis. For logarithmic on both use a loglog plot.

Thank you a lot. I've tried to improve the code (all is reported as an edit the initial post). I've used semilogx because with loglog plot I've obtained a straight horizontal line. What do you think about that latter code?

But now you get to explore a correctly computed solution. Previous insights into the graph do not apply. Is the scale reasonable? Initial slope 1 and time span $\pi/2$ gives an estimate of scale 1 for the solution, not $10^{-13}$.

there's something wrong for sure, but I don't know what it is. Also, I noticed that in the second line of the loop, I wrote k1=f(T(n+1),a,a), but            k1=f(T(n+1) ,V(1,n),V(2,n) ); should be more correct. But that modification results in an incorrect solution. How can I explore a correctly computed solution?

Double error. the basis point for the step is always T(n) and V(:,n). So yes, k1 needs to be corrected that way, but also the other slopes need the time/angle corrected. // The cleanest solution for the shifted first point would be to define T=linspace(0,b,N+1), then shift T(1)=a, and in the loop for each step compute h=T(n+1)-T(n).

I've tried to fix the other slopes by substituting T(n+1) with T(n). In this way  the scale of solution drastically increase and the solution starts to increase at x=0.05 as I shown in figure in the former post. Do you think it is fine?

This now looks quite reasonable. The scale fits, the tangent goes from horizontal to vertical. A next verification step could be to compare the solutions to different step sizes.
